# Beam Span and Size for Pool House

Tags: roof, structural, shed, beam

I am building a simple pool house with a large overhang roof.
Main issue I have is figuring out what beam size and span I need to support the roof properly.
Key Features:

- Total Roof width: 29ft
- Distance between Posts: 27ft (center to center)
- Roof Type: 2x12wood with 2 by 12 Pitch (~10degrees)
- Location: Ontario, Canada (snow load)

I was told I need a 10" Steel Beam but have some questions:

- What specific size of beam?
- Does it span the full width of the roof or can it stop at the posts?
- Do I need LVL or steel beams going from cross-beam to the shed that is 10ft distance or can the 2x12 carry that load/distance?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an engineering matter, the beam size is provided for your first-hand information use only. Confirmation from a structural engineer is required for construction.

Deck length tributary to the beam = (20' - 5' - 0.5)/2 + 2.5 = 9.75', say 10'. Assume 5 psf misc. wt. on top of the snow load (S), the uniform distribute load on beam (with 10% increase for beam self wt.), w = 1.1*(S+10)*10. Beam span length (column - column), L = 27', deflection limit = L/240 = 1.35".

The roof snow load across the province of Ontario varies from 40 psf to 70 psf (approx.) Per the Allowable Stress Design (ASD) method, and Fy = 36 ksi, fb = 21.6 ksi, the estimated wide flange beam sizes for the corresponding snow loads are as listed below:

Snow Load - Beam size*

40 - W10x30

50 - W10x33

60 - W10x39

70 - W10x45

(*) - All beam sizes are governed by the deflection criteria.